# Why is my timezone one hour off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, timezone

Running this code...

```
Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') do
  p Time.zone.now
end
```

I get the following: `=> Sun, 14 Apr 2013 20:30:53 PDT -07:00`

Yet when I do Rails Time Zone Select.... it says `-8:00` quite clearly. Why is it -7 in one area and -8 in another?

Other times, time zones like `Hawaii` which are `-10:00` don't get offset by an hour.

I assume this has something to do with DST, but I'm more curious whether it means it's working *properly* or *improperly* and there is something else I need to do.

Ultimately I'm using this in a datepicker, and I find it very odd that when I use `Time.zone.parse` (along with my time zone around filter), its offsetting everything by 1 hour.

THanks

Comment: it maybe that support for daylight savings is turned off in the apps where it is not showing daylight savings correctly.